# C# NModbus get String form byte[]

Tags: c#, mono, modbus, bcd

I using NModbus4.dll to communicate with modbus device.
I read this register:

Register: 0257-0288

Number of registers:32

Variable name: monitor buffer area

Data type: BCD

Description: readable

Using this code:

```
byte slaveId = byte.Parse ("1");
ushort startAddress = 257;
ushort[] readValue =  _serialMaster.ReadHoldingRegisters(slaveId, startAddress, 32);
byte[] asciiValue = Modbus.Utility.ModbusUtility.GetAsciiBytes(readValue);
string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(asciiValue);
```

I use [this converter](https://codebeautify.org/hex-string-converter) to convert from hex to text and i get this:

**epO tureD aiemet r      7 646.58  mm   4**

This register is to read device lcd content, and this content is:

**Pipe Outer Perimeter
     2345.78 mm**

I can't get correct lcd content.

Answer (score 0):

According to [source code](https://github.com/NModbus4/NModbus4/blob/portable-3.0/NModbus4/Utility/ModbusUtility.cs), `GetAsciiBytes` method applies the conversation with `UTF8`;

```
string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(asciiValue);
```

Comment: I already try this, but it give's me same results. I changed post.

Comment: I think, there is no mistake in the code. Would you try to set register count to read as 16 or 64 ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem. There  is no problem in code, device response is bad.